# Regex to extract everything in the quotes in bash shell?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

Consider this datafile

> random text "txt" random text
>   random text "txt1" random text "txt2"
>   random text "txt1" random text "txt3"
>   random text "txt1" random text "txt4"
>   random text "txt1" random text "txt5"
>   random text "txt1" random text "txt5" random text "txt6" random text

For each of this line, I need to extract everything inside the quotes, I.E.

> txt 
>   txt1,txt2
>   txt1,txt3
>   txt1,txt4
>   txt1,txt5
>   txt1,txt5,txt6
>   There can be multiple quotes in a single line.

I wrote this regex in shell(actually I wrote a sed command,but when I paste it here, it screws up the .*)

> ^dotStar"[^"]+"dotStar$(for single number quote)
>   ^dotStar"[^"]+"dotStar"[^"]+"dotStar$(if there are two quotes)

As you can see, my regex is dependent on the number of quotes appearing. Can anyone give me a generic reg-ex, which irrespective on the number of times quotes is appearing, it gives me the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed --posix 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)"[^"]*/\1,/g;s/\(.*\),/\1/' input.txt
```

Output:

```
txt
txt1,txt2
txt1,txt3
txt1,txt4
txt1,txt5
txt1,txt5,txt6
```

Comment: I think you might have a small error:  This works for me, but it's based on yours which is very clever: 
`sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)"/\1,/g;s/\(.*\),.*/\1/'`

Comment: What is the advantage of that?

Comment: I narrowed it down a bit further.  Yours doesn't work for me, but it does if you change `\+` to `*`

Comment: Hmmm. Which version of sed are you using?

Comment: looks like bsd sed that came with my mac.  That's probably the difference.

Comment: I'm just using POSIX syntax. Can you post the output of `sed --version`? Will try to get and compile that version for Linux and try to reproduce the problem

Comment: If I am not wrong, in mac + operator does not work. You have replace a+ with a(a)*

Comment: Thx, for the hint! I've checked it using the `--posix` option and you are right: `\+` is not POSIX. As a solution I suggest to simply replace `\+` by `*`. This will work in this case. Also thanks to @JohnC for finding that problem!